# Тире во фразеологизме

Tags: пунктуация

Известное выражение "для бешеной собаки пять верст (—) не крюк". А нужно ли тут тире после слова "верст"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тире не нужно, так как между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит отрицательная частица НЕ.